# iOS tableview data change

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tableview

i've a method that populate a `UITableView` without problem.
if i go to setting page, change some settings and come back to my rootview i call the method with new settings but my `UITableView` display always the last values.
Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[self.tableview reloadData];